# How can I replace items within a list in python3 using a condition?

Tags: python, list

Write a function which prints all integers between 0 and 100:
For every number that is divisible by **7** or has the digit **7** print `‘boom’` instead of the number itself.

My solution so far:

```
def boom():
r = []
for i in range(1, 100):
    if i % 7 == 0 or '7' in str(i):
        r.append("boom")
    else:
        r.append(i)
return r
```

print(boom())

Helped by: AkshayNevrekar

Question: Do you find a better way to solve this specific problem? a better algorithm? Thanks!

Comment: You haven't asked anything about your "solution".

Comment: Does your solution work? If it doesn't, what is exactly wrong?

Comment: It is funny because in "your" solution you the functions takes input `n` and it is never called. :/

Comment: Why are you passing an argument to `Boom` if you never use it?

Comment: what is `idx`? it is never defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

You need to check if *i* is divisible by **7** if yes then add `'BOOM'` to your result list. Now if a number has digit **7** in it or not has to be checked you can typecast *i* to string and use `in` to check if 7 is present or not. If *i* not divisible by 7 and it doesn't contain 7 in it then just append *i* to your result list.

```
def boom():
    return ['BOOM' if i%7==0 or '7' in str(i) else i for i in range(1,101)]
print(boom())

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'BOOM', 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 'BOOM', 15, 16, 'BOOM', 18, 19, 20, 'BOOM', 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 'BOOM', 36, 'BOOM', 38, 39, 40, 41, 'BOOM', 43, 44, 45, 46, 'BOOM', 48, 'BOOM', 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 'BOOM', 64, 65, 66, 'BOOM', 68, 69, 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 80, 81, 82, 83, 'BOOM', 85, 86, 'BOOM', 88, 89, 90, 'BOOM', 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 99, 100]
```

---

```
def boom(n:int,inp:str):
    return [inp if i%7==0 or '7' in str(i) else i for i in range(1,n+1)]

print(boom(20,'7 used to be here'))

for i in boom(20,'7 used to be here'):
    print(i)
```

Here, `n` is range and `inp` is string that replaces the number which has 7 in it or divisible by 7.

---

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, '7 used to be here', 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, '7 used to be here', 15, 16, '7 used to be here', 18, 19, 20]

1
2
3
4
5
6
7 used to be here
8
9
10
11
12
13
7 used to be here
15
16
7 used to be here
18
19
20
```

Try this to make your `boom()` complete.

```
def boom(n=100,inp='BOOM'):
    return [inp if i%7==0 or '7' in str(i) else i for i in range(1,n+1)]
```

1. If `boom()` is called with no parameters then it considers n to be *101* and inp as `'BOOM'`.
2. If `boom(n=x)` is called then it considers range to be *x+1* and inp as `'BOOM'`
3. If `boom(inp=any_string)` is called then it considers range to be *101* and inp as any_string.
4. if `boom(n=x,inp=any_string)` is called then it considers range to be *x+1* and inp to be any_string.

---

output

```
>>> boom()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'BOOM', 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 'BOOM', 15, 16, 'BOOM', 18, 19, 20, 'BOOM', 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 'BOOM', 36, 'BOOM', 38, 39, 40, 41, 'BOOM', 43, 44, 45, 46, 'BOOM', 48, 'BOOM', 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 'BOOM', 64, 65, 66, 'BOOM', 68, 69, 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 80, 81, 82, 83, 'BOOM', 85, 86, 'BOOM', 88, 89, 90, 'BOOM', 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 99, 100]
>>> boom(50)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'BOOM', 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 'BOOM', 15, 16, 'BOOM', 18, 19, 20, 'BOOM', 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 'BOOM', 'BOOM', 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 'BOOM', 36, 'BOOM', 38, 39, 40, 41, 'BOOM', 43, 44, 45, 46, 'BOOM', 48, 'BOOM', 50]
>>> boom(inp='hehe')
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'hehe', 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 'hehe', 15, 16, 'hehe', 18, 19, 20, 'hehe', 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 'hehe', 'hehe', 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 'hehe', 36, 'hehe', 38, 39, 40, 41, 'hehe', 43, 44, 45, 46, 'hehe', 48, 'hehe', 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 'hehe', 'hehe', 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 'hehe', 64, 65, 66, 'hehe', 68, 69, 'hehe', 'hehe', 'hehe', 'hehe', 'hehe', 'hehe', 'hehe', 'hehe', 'hehe', 'hehe', 80, 81, 82, 83, 'hehe', 85, 86, 'hehe', 88, 89, 90, 'hehe', 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 'hehe', 'hehe', 99, 100]
>>> boom(n=77,inp='77777')
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, '77777', 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, '77777', 15, 16, '77777', 18, 19, 20, '77777', 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, '77777', '77777', 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, '77777', 36, '77777', 38, 39, 40, 41, '77777', 43, 44, 45, 46, '77777', 48, '77777', 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, '77777', '77777', 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, '77777', 64, 65, 66, '77777', 68, 69, '77777', '77777', '77777', '77777', '77777', '77777', '77777', '77777']
```

Comment: thank you! I understand the exercise much better now :)

Comment: For your last part, wouldn't it be easier to set `n=100` instead of `None` and `inp="BOOM"` instead of `None` and avoid the case checking?

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes, you are right. I don't know how I overlooked this. I feel dumb. Thanks for pointing out. Editing the answer right away.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
def boom(n):
    r = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if i %7==0 or '7' in str(i):
            r.append("boom")
        else:
            r.append(i)
    return r

print(boom(100))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def Boom():
  return list(map(lambda a: 'Boom' if (a % 7 == 0 or '7' in str(a)) else a, range(0, 100)));

print(Boom())

['Boom', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'Boom', 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 'Boom', ..., 99]
```

Comment: Not quite you still have the case of digits 70-79

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Oh :facepalm: fixed again '^^

Comment: why the `list(map(...))`? wouldn't it be simpler as a list comprehension? or better yet, generator-comprehension?